# Cannot read property 'createManager' of undefined

Tags: javascript, sails.js

I need sails.js to dynamically create a new datastore adapter and connection url, and I come across this solution https://sailsjs.com/documentation/reference/waterline-orm/datastores/driver, where it stated that I can use the stateless driver to do it.

But somehow I ended up with this error

```sh
TypeError: Cannot read property 'createManager' of undefined
```

Here is my sample code:

```js
let Driver = sails.getDatastore().driver;

let connectionUrl = `postgresql://postgres:postgres@localhost/test-db`;

let manager = (
    await Driver.createManager({ connectionString: connectionUrl })
).manager;
```

By the way, my sails version is `1.2.1`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks, I was able to do it with npm package - machinepack-postgresql instead:

https://github.com/node-machine/driver-interface

```
let dynamicDb = require('machinepack-postgresql');

let connectionUrl = `postgresql://postgres:postgres@localhost/test-db`;

let manager = (
    await dynamicDb.createManager({ connectionString: connectionUrl })
).manager;

let db;
try {
    db = (
        await dynamicDb.getConnection({ manager: manager })
    ).connection;
} catch (err) {
    await dynamicDb.destroyManager({ manager: manager });
    return err;
}

let [err, data] = await flatry(dynamicDb.sendNativeQuery({
    connection: db,
    nativeQuery: 'select * from table1'
}));

if (err) {
    return err;
}

await dynamicDb.destroyManager({ manager: manager });
```

Answer (score 1):

> This property is not guaranteed to exist for all database adapters. If
>   the datastore's underlying adapter does not support the standardized
>   driver interface, then driver will not exist

As clearly stated by documentation your **datasource's underlying adapter does not support the standardized driver interface** so the `driver` is undefined that's why you're getting,

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'createManager' of undefined
```